# Gitlab CI Job on push tags on branch not triggering

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want a certain job to trigger when a tag is pushed to main branch

I have the following gitlab ci config

```yaml
job1:
    rules:
      - if: ($CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)/ && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main")
```

I usually do the following in git

```
git checkout main
git merge develop
git tag "1.0.0"
git push --atomic origin main "1.0.0"
```

However it is not triggering, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of pipelines that can be triggered in GitLab. What [pre-defined variables are available](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) will differ depending on the type of pipeline. As per the documentation:

- `CI_COMMIT_TAG` is "available only in pipelines for tags."
- `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is "available in branch pipelines."

Since your pipeline is not going to be a tag pipeline and branch pipeline at the same time, your condition will never evaluate to true.

I suggest only using the first part where you've specified the formatting for the tag.

Comment: I never noticed that in the docs, thanks for pointing it out!